# dynamic content in kml balloon from url

Tags: kml, google-earth, google-earth-plugin, balloon

I have a server that is serving up an xhtml page with all of the content I want displayed in my google earth (or worldwind) balloon.  I would like the placemark balloon to fetch the html page when it is clicked on the map.   To make it simple, I want my balloon to be www.yahoo.com when you click it from the map.

Any searching online sends me to java code that can hook into the google earth api.  I am really hoping there is a client side kml way to do this.  Is there an extended data tag or description tag I can use to get this to work?  I have even tried to use the embed tag which works great for a you tube video but there is no plugin for an html page.   Any help is much appreciated.

This works too but an iframe is pretty ugly -

```
<Placemark> 
  <name>Test Placemark</name> 
    <description> 
      <![CDATA[ 
        <iframe src="http://www.yahoo.com" frameborder="0" 
           scrolling="auto" height="500" width="600"></iframe> 
      ]]> 
    </description> 
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try the getBalloonHtmlUnsafe() and the HtmlDivBalloon?  https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/balloons#getballoonhtmlunsafe

However you are adding the kml to the page you could then bind a click function to those placemarks.

```
google.earth.fetchKml(ge, url, function(kmlObject){
   if(kmlObject){
      ge.getFeatures().appendChild(kmlObject);

      if(kmlObject.getType() === 'KmlPlacemark'){
          google.earth.addEventListener(kmlObject, 'click', function(event){
               event.preventDefault();

               var balloon = ge.createHtmlDivBalloon('');
               var content = kmlObject.getBalloonHtmlUnsafe();
               balloon.setFeature(kmlObject);
               var div = document.createElement('div');
               div.innerHTML = content;
               balloon.setContentDiv(div);

               ge.setBalloon(balloon);
          });
      }
   }
});
```

If that still doesn't work, remember that google earth scrubs a lot of balloon data so you might try using jquery to inject the html.

```
var balloon = ge.createHtmlDivBalloon('');
var content = kmlObject.getBalloonHtmlUnsafe();
balloon.setFeature(kmlObject);
var div = document.createElement('div');
balloon.setContentDiv(div);

ge.setBalloon(balloon);
$(div).html(content);
```