# Embedded Youtube videos not appearing in infowindows

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, kml, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I am attempting to embed Youtube videos into some of the infowindows in the following KML file:

http://www.jonangfoundation.org/files/newdef.kml .

The videos show up fine on Google Earth and KML Builder, but on this page they do not show up at all:

http://www.jonangfoundation.org/taktentest

Anyone know what could be keeping them from showing up?

Comment: There is no map on [that page](http://www.jonangfoundation.org/taktentest), it says "Page not found"

Comment: My apologies: the map is now located at http://www.jonangfoundation.org/valley

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your 'test' page does not load - Page Not Found error.
However, I think you need to set the correct MIME type for .kml files. Your newdef.kml is presented in my browser window as XML rather than downloaded as a .kml file. That *might* be your problem, it is hard to tell with nothing else to go on. check out this link for details about setting the right MIME

https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut#kml_server

Edit: I am not sure what is going on. Your KML code looks okay to me, and I see you have tried a few different approaches, none of which appear to work. I suggest you visit [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254449/dynamic-content-in-kml-balloon-from-url), as it's answer is something you could do to make it work.

Basically, you override the default behaviour when a placemark gets clicked, and allow iframes and javascript to be used in the balloon. It is the original way of getting around your problem (however I thought it was fixed in recent version of the plug-in. Maybe not?)

Comment: Thank you for your help.

The error is my fault.  The page has actually moved to www.jonangfoundation.org/valley

As for the problem, if it was because of the MIME type, wouldn't that mean that none of the KML data gets loaded?  In this case, everything but the iframes with the Youtube videos is loading correctly (placemarkers, infowindow text content).  Might this be a problem with my server or browser configuration?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I believe your content is being scrubbed. See link for description and possible work around.
https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/balloons#scrubbing